# Terraform not starting the nginx server on AWS

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, terraform

I am having the below terraform file where I am starting a Nginx server. Terraform is installing Nginx but the Nginx server did not start. I have to manually login to the ec2-machine and start the service. Where am i going wrong?

```
terraform {
 required_version = ">=0.12, <0.13"
}

provider "aws" { 
    region = "ap-south-1" 
} 
resource "aws_instance" "ec2-instance" { 
    ami = "ami-04b2519c83e2a7ea5" 
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.web_security.id]
    key_name = "kops-keypair"
    user_data = <<-EOF
                    #!/bin/bash
                    sudo yum update -y
                    sudo yum install nginx -y 
                    sudo service start nginx
                EOF
    tags = {
        Name = "nginx-instance",
        created-date = "22-04-2020"
    }
} 

resource "aws_security_group" "web_security" {
    name = "web-security"

  ingress {
     from_port = 22
     to_port = 22
     protocol = "tcp" 
     cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  ingress {
     from_port = 80
     to_port = 80
     protocol = "tcp" 
     cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  } 
  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My bad. The command should be `sudo service nginx start`